# configure ofbiz pos alone

Tags: point-of-sale, ofbiz

I want to know how to use ofbiz-pos alone in my machine. For this POS what are the minimum things are required (softwares). Whether we need to install the entire ofbiz framework in POS machine to run POS application??

Can any one help me to resolve this questions

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as a "full featured" Apache OFBiz installation.

You basicly just need Java 6 (and a "real" database for production, but for testing/evaluation the embedded Derby is good enough), see https://cwiki.apache.org/OFBTECH/apache-ofbiz-technical-production-setup-guide.html for details (of course you don't need the Url/Ports/SSL-Settings if you aren't using the web interface)